# Rtf to WordML Convert in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a windows application to generate report.
It has templates in RTF as "`{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang2057{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Arial;}}\r\n\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\fs20\\tab\\tab\\tab\\tab af\\par\r\n}\r\n"`, which is written to word doc file. then the word is Saved-As XML and close. Then, tags like (say)  are extracted and some new

The problem here is Word, which is used as converter in the process and it consumes valuable time in Loop, where it opens word instance, save, close, delete.

Please correct any mistake if i have made and help me with an alternative to convert to WordML .

Comment: your question is not very clear. What is that you are trying to do?

Comment: I just got information by searching, that it is WordML format i need to convert to, from RTF

Comment: Why i am down voted? Is there something wring with question? Some one explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Aspose .Words

```
//your rtf string
string rtfStrx = "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang2057{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Arial;}}\r\n\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\fs20\\tab\\tab\\tab\\tab af\\par\r\n}\r\n"

//convert string to bytes for memory stream
byte[] rtfBytex = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rtfStrx);
MemoryStream rtfStreamx = new MemoryStream(rtfBytex);

Document rtfDocx = new Document(rtfStreamx);

rtfDocx.Save(@"C:\Temp.xml", SaveFormat.WordML);
```

This saves your RTF text in new document as WordML. I cannot say about time it will take in loop. But it will surely have much less time then MS Word being physically opened and closed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, I assume that you are trying to create Office XML file from RTF template? I think you can use [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en) for creation of the xml file. Specifically, DocumentReflector that comes with that SDK seems to a good fit for that. See this [example](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/alspeirs/archive/2008/12/09/generating-documents-with-c-open-xml-and-the-document-reflector.aspx). Also, there is a http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/richedit/conversions/article.php/c5377/ which shows how to convert from RTF to HTML that might guide you.

Answer (score -2):

use wpf richtextbox.  Rtf => xaml.  Since xaml is xml_ use xslt or linq to convert it to your desired xml structure

Comment: hi, thanks for solution. 1) we use .net 2.0 vs2005 only. i can talk to business about same 2) can you elaborate more on this please.