# Appending Contents of two RichTextbox as a single RichText string

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I want to append the contents of two rich text boxes in a Windows Forms .Net application; say: `stringText = richtextbox1.Rtf + richtextbox2.Rtf;` The `stringText` should be RTF text, which should have \rtf line once, having concatenated rich text.

The Clipboard is not in scope here.

Also, I'm curious, if we can de-merge them.

Comment: If you link this to my previous question, to convert RTF to WordML, yes it remains unsolved. XAML as solution is not applicable in .net 2.0 winForms, while using XML SDK is last option, i am advised to use, by my manager, as that would take time. I am suggested to merge RTF rich strings and substiture in WordML, and do conversion of this new RTF and demerge & insert in WordML. I know that does not sound good, but, i have to report exactly that.

Comment: Can you convert RTF to WordML yet?

Comment: If I was faced with these problems, I'd probably just buy Aspose Words and move on to the next project.

Comment: I recommended that to project, but they enforced to build something in-house.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
richTextBoxTarget.Select(richTextBoxTarget.TextLength, 0);
richTextBoxTarget.SelectedRtf = richTextBoxSource.Rtf;
```

This merges the contents of richTextBoxSource to the end of richTextBoxTarget. It automatically creates valid RTF with only one \rtf tag.
To de-merge, also use `Select`and `SelectedRtf`. The only requirement here is, that you need to know, at what position you want to split.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, the confusion might be that your example shows only 1 source, so it looks like you aren't addressing the problem of merging the RTF from 2 sources.

Comment: @adrift: No, it doesn't. It contains two sources. It adds the contents of one RTB to the end of another RTB which in turn can already containt Rtf text.

Comment: hi Daniel, i appreciate your answer. But, my requirement is different here. This is linked to my original requirement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944813/rtf-to-wordml-convert-in-c

Comment: I am still convinced, that my answer does help you. I don't see, how your requirement in the other question leads to my solution not working. Could you please explain? Basically, when you assign a Rtf text to the SelectedRtf property of the RichTextBox class, it streams the assigned Rtf data into the already existing data, which results in a merge of the two Rtf data. According to your question, that is exactly what you want. richTextBoxTarget.Rtf contains the **merged** Rtf. That is exactly what you were asking in your question: "stringText =richtextbox1.Rtf + richtextbox2.Rtf;"

Comment: Yes sir, it merges two multiple richtextboxes, butproblem lies in de-merging. How do i de-merge them. I do have point of seperation for them. The aim of merging and de-merging is i want to word operation once and convert to WordML and then demerge. Is there some tag or guardbit something i can attach, so that i could de-merge them.

Comment: You could simply remember the position you inserted the second part in. On a related note: I don't understand AT ALL what you are trying to achieve ;)

Comment: On similar note, I suggested you solution in your question in link above. Did you tried that first?

Comment: As per the question, i framed, Daniel, you gave me write answer.  @pooja: yes, i saw that, will try now and let you know on original thread

Comment: how to do the same thing in wpf with c#?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old question, but it seems to be a common one. Thus, I'm gonna add my answer to this, cause the marked answer make RTF's to concatenate, but it also gives an extra new line, every time.

This would be:

```
RichTextBoxSource.Select(0,RichTextBoxSource.TextLength);
RichTextBoxTarget.SelectedRtf = richTextBoxSource.SelectedRtf;
```

It's easy and works fine. Hope it will help somebody:)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is useful, but here's the above code re-formatted into an extension method.
This lets you say:

```
textBox.AppendRtf(someRtfString)
```

which handily matches up with the `RichTextBox` class's `AppendText()` method.

```
''' <summary>
''' Appends the provided RTF-formatted string to the provided <see cref="RichTextBox"/>.
''' </summary>
<Extension()> _
Public Sub AppendRtf(ByVal rtbTextBox As RichTextBox, ByVal strRtf As String)
    rtbTextBox.Select(rtbTextBox.TextLength, 0)
    rtbTextBox.SelectedRtf = strRtf
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

well since I can't comment Pawel anwser, I must add that besides his code:

```
RichTextBoxSource.Select(0,RichTextBoxSource.TextLength);
RichTextBoxTarget.SelectedRtf = richTextBoxSource.SelectedRtf;
```

you should add if you want the new text to be always on the top

```
RichTextBoxTarget.Select(0,0);
```

or if you want it to be always on the bottom

```
RichTextBoxTarget.Select(RichTextBoxTarget.TextLength,0);
```

So you also have control of the position like in Daniel answer, even if the target richtextbox is clickable.