# Print report from 3 different richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, richtextbox

I have three different richtextbox that the end user can modify : header, body, footer  of document.
How can i print a report from the three richtextbox

Header

body

footer

thanks

Comment: By creating report, adding appropriate parts and probably drawing same content as richtextboxes has. For starter: [RichTextBox printing](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/673996/RichTextBox-Printing-in-Csharp-with-WinForms-VS)

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to merge the 3 boxes together. There is a question with answer about how to do this here: [Appending Contents of two RichTextbox as a single RichText string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994454/appending-contents-of-two-richtextbox-as-a-single-richtext-string)

After that you will have to print this merged content. A tutorial about how to do this can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970917(v=vs.110).aspx .