# RichTextBox and special chars c#

Tags: c#, special-characters, richtextbox, rtf

I need to put text with RTF format in a richtextbox, I try to put it with the `richtextbox.rtf = TextString` parameter, but the problem is that the string has special chars and the richtextbox does not show all the string correctly. The String and code that I am using:

String (TextString):

`╔═══This is only an example, the special characters may change═══╗`

C# Code:

```
String TextString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(TextBytes);
String TextRTF = @"{\rtf1\ansi " + TextString + "}";
richtextbox1.Rtf = TextRTF;
```

With this code, richtextbox show "+---This is only an example, the special characters may change---+" and in some cases, show "??????".

How can i solve this problem? if i change `\rtf1\ansi` to `\rtf1\utf-8`, i not see changes.

Comment: _I need to put text with RTF format in a richtextbox, I try to put it with the richtextbox.rtf = TextString parameter_ You problem with fonts aside: You really should manipulate the Rtf of a RTB only when it is really necessary. See [here for the rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295523/how-do-i-send-varying-text-sized-strings-from-one-richtextbox-to-another/30296255?s=2|0.1630#30296255) of how to change RTB content!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the `Text` property:

```
richTextBox1.Text = "╔═══This is only an example, the special characters may change═══╗";
```

If you want to use the `RTF` property:
Take a look at this question: [How to output unicode string to RTF (using C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368020/how-to-output-unicode-string-to-rtf-using-c)

You need to use something like this to convert the special characters to rtf format:

```
static string GetRtfUnicodeEscapedString(string s)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in s)
    {
        if(c == '\\' || c == '{' || c == '}')
            sb.Append(@"\" + c);
        else if (c <= 0x7f)
            sb.Append(c);
        else
            sb.Append("\\u" + Convert.ToUInt32(c) + "?");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then use:

```
richtextbox1.Rtf = GetRtfUnicodeEscapedString(TextString);
```