# Proper way to add a list of strings that include words with accents to a RichEditText box

Tags: c#, string, list, richtextbox, diacritics

I am trying to add a list of strings that contain special characters such as accents to a RichEditText box.  To be exact, it is list of peoples names. Some are in French & Spanish for instance.  Unfortunately, these special characters are showing up incorrectly.

I am currently do the following:

```
aRichEditTextBox.Lines = nameList.ToArray();
```

For instance... Instead of "Añazgo", I am getting this "A�azgo".

What is the proper or best way to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Can you check the nameList content before assigning it to RichEditText box and be sure that it has "Añazgo"?

Comment: Where is the `nameList` content coming from?

Comment: @Jackdraw, I am using Windows Forms

Comment: @Jimi, it is a list<string> where the data comes from a text file.

Comment: Yes, sure, so the source is a text file. Which is the encoding used to write to this file? `Encoding.Default`? Can you post a sample of this file? - Or, open the file in Notepad, see whether you can read it correctly, then save it using UTF-8 as the Encoding

Comment: @AliIhsanElmas, I know what the data looks like because it is being read from a text file into a List<string>.  When looking at the list items in the debugger, I am seeing the accents in the names of the individuals listed in the List<string>.

Comment: @Jimi...  here is a sample of what is in the text file.

Añazgo, Carlos
Deza, Silvia
Garcia, Tomás
Reyes, José
Suárez, María

Comment: That's not what I asked and suggested. Open the file in Notepad and save it as UTF-8. Then try again. Remember to use a Font that contains those characters.

Comment: @Jimi, yes, saving it as UTF-8 seemed to have worked.

Comment: Right. From now on, only use UTF-8 to store text. If you don't, you can read it in your Computer, most probably, others cannot read it correctly (or at all) in other machines that use a different Language and CodePages. Building a software, you cannot consider the Local Encoding as a valid encoding for text. UTF-8 can render Unicode CodePoints of any Language and is interpreted everywhere.

Comment: @Jimi, thanks for the help!  The text file is not one created by me and is being provided by someone else.  This means I will have to add code to convert the text file first to UTF-8 before adding the names to my sting list.

Comment: Ah, well, sure. Then, read the source text specifying the Encoding used (it should be CodePage 1252), then save it all with `File.WriteAllText([Path], [Text])`. The default Encoding in .Net is UTF-8, so you don't need to specify the encoding when saving text.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use an RTF format for the richtextbox to recognize those special character,
use this method that came from here - [RichTextBox and special chars c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30361853/richtextbox-and-special-chars-c-sharp)

```
static string GetRtfUnicodeEscapedString(string s)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in s)
    {
        if(c == '\\' || c == '{' || c == '}')
            sb.Append(@"\" + c);
        else if (c <= 0x7f)
            sb.Append(c);
        else
            sb.Append("\\u" + Convert.ToUInt32(c) + "?");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

richtextbox1.Rtf = GetRtfUnicodeEscapedString(TextString);
```