# How do I change the text in a RichTextBox size and removing the highlight on the text?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

This is my code. When I open a text file it's changing the font size of the text but then coloring all the text making it highlight like I select all the text.

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog theDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            theDialog.Title = "Open Text File";
            theDialog.Filter = "TXT files|*.txt";
            theDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string filename = theDialog.FileName;
                richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
                this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
                this.richTextBox1.SelectionLength = this.richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                this.richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Maiandra GD", 30);
                string s = richTextBox1.Text;
                richTextBox1.Clear();
                richTextBox1.Text = s;
            }
        }
```

I tried to add this:

```
string s = richTextBox1.Text;
richTextBox1.Clear();
richTextBox1.Text = s;
```

It did the trick but the problem is that the text now back to it's original small size.
I also tried before it to add this:

```
this.richTextBox.SelectionStart = 0;
this.richTextBox.SelectionLength = richTextBox.Text.Length;     
this.richTextBox.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
```

But this didn't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the Text property directly.: `richTextBox1.Text = s;` Never do this or `richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filename);` if you don't want to mess up any formatting. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295523/how-do-i-send-varying-text-sized-strings-from-one-richtextbox-to-another/30296255?s=1|0.0000#30296255) for the rules!

Change this

```
        if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string filename = theDialog.FileName;
            richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
            this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
            this.richTextBox1.SelectionLength = this.richTextBox1.Text.Length;
            this.richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Maiandra GD", 30);
            string s = richTextBox1.Text;
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            richTextBox1.Text = s;
        }
```

to this:

```
        if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string filename = theDialog.FileName;
            string s = File.ReadAllText(filename);

            this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;  // or wherever you want to insert..
            this.richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
            this.richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Maiandra GD", 30);
            this.richTextBox1.SelectdText = s;
        }
```

I don't know about the 'highlighting' you mention but as you are inserting text outside of the selection it is probably reverting the text to the default font & attributes you had set before..